# How to independently test ajax POST calls for any web application

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, unit-testing

how can i test my ajax calls (POST) independently without actually triggering it from frontend. 
Suppose, i have developed an ajax call and built everything for the backend (java) but my frontend part is not yet developed.
In this kind of scenario, how can i unit test my ajax query and can check what data it is sending back.

Kindly help. I am a slow learner but if you find this post inappropriate at least provide one url where i can learn on this kind of testing

Comment: [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/api-testing-with-telerik-fiddler), [Google](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

The most versatile tool for this purpose is [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). Give it a try.